# Resetting the auto incrementing column

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    eId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    eName1 VARCHAR(30),
    eName2 VARCHAR(30),
    eType VARCHAR(30),
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(12),
    eSalary INT,
    birthday DATE,
    imageFile VARCHAR(100)
);
SELECT*FROM employee; 
ALTER TABLE employee AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

When I perform `ALTER TABLE employee AUTO_INCREMENT =1;`, it simply doesn't work :(
It says 0 rows affected.
[image]

This is the data in the table.

Comment: Is there data still in your table?

Comment: If the table is just created, then there are no rows.

Comment: You are assuming he's added a DROP. (He's just edited it to add a data screenshot, so it's possible it's existing).

Comment: Yes! eId are 2 and 3.. I'm trying to make them 1 and 2. But ```ALTER TABLE employee AUTO_INCREMENT =1;``` doesnt work for me...

Comment: You can't go lower than your lowest value.

Comment: When there is data, you need to TRUNCATE the table, to start with 1.

Comment: You can also use **TRUNCATE TABLE** . it erase all data in the table and create it new

Comment: it exists mb, I forgot to show the dta in the table.

Comment: huh, so I can't go below 2 in this case. If I truncate the table, does that mean I have to insert data manually? Because I'm trying to connect this to javafx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will reset your eId, starting from 1:

```
UPDATE `tbl1`, (
  SELECT @loop := 0
  FROM
   `tbl1`
  ) t
SET `eId` = (@loop := @loop + 1)
```

If you want to change the starting eId, just modify the `0` in `@loop := 0`

Comment: is t after the bracket and before SET neccessary?

Comment: Yes. The subquery needs an alias.

Comment: hmm, it gives me an error saying duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Maybe because I added another row with eId 4?

Comment: I assume you've changed the `@loop := 0` to `@loop := 4`?

Comment: So, what's happening is the loop is making it to 4 before eId 4 is replaced. Depending on how many rows you have, you could add `+ 1000` to the end of the code I provided to change them to a higher number, then revert it back and rerun it. You would not come across any duplicate entries at that point.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE ... AUTO_INCREMENT = N can only change the auto-increment counter value to a value larger than the current maximum.

In your case , you can set it to 4 or 4+.

Source:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html